# Adding QQuickItem pointers to an std::map makes them all "not accessible" pointers or items

Tags: c++11, iterator, stdmap, stdarray, qquickitem

This question involves *Qt* but could be pure *C++* problem with my logic.

I am adding `QQuickItem`s to an `std::map` store info about a list of `QQuickItem`s & their respective parents.

**The code:**

```
std::array<std::string, 2> ObjectNamesArray = { "quickitemObj1", "quickitemObj2" };

std::map<QQuickItem*, QQuickItem*> items;

for(const auto& quickitem: ObjectNamesArray) {

    QQuickItem * item = Qmlengine->rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickItem*>(quickitem.c_str());

    if (item != NULL)
       items.insert(std::make_pair(item, item->parent());

    // for a test, following works fine with the item pointer within this loop
    qreal width ? item->width();
}
```

Debugging through above loop, the `items` map shows zero items with the tag **not accessible**.

Iterating over the map again like this.

```
std::map<QQuickItem*, QQuickItem*>::iterator it = items.begin();
while (it != items.end()) {

    QQuickItem* item = it->first;
    QQuickItem * itemParent = it->second;  // crashes here as *item is null
    it++;
}
```

**Problem:**

But, when I try to iterate through the map, there are no valid pointers to my `QQuickItem`s. In fact looks like there are not items added to the map.

**Question:**

What is wrong with my logic? How should I add `QQuickItem`s to an std::map so that I can safely retrieve them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have const string inside this method istead of `QQuickItem` name

```
findChild<QQuickItem*>("quickitem.c_str()");
```

So it gives you 0
You should add checking if `item` is NULL before adding to container.

Second thing is that you talking about searching `items` map, but here, you are appending to `parents`

```
parents.insert(std::make_pair(item, item->parent());
```

BTW: When you use Qt, I recommend you using [Qt containers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/containers.html)

**EDIT:**

This works for me, after some improvements and if i have appropriate objects in QML

CPP

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
    return -1;

std::array<std::string, 2> ObjectNamesArray = { "quickitemObj1", "quickitemObj2" };

std::map<QQuickItem*, QQuickItem*> items;

for(const auto& quickitem: ObjectNamesArray) {

    QQuickItem * item = engine.rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickItem*>(quickitem.c_str());

    if (item != NULL)
       items.insert(std::make_pair(item, (QQuickItem*)item->parent()));
}

std::cout << "Map: " << items.size() << std::endl; //it gives 2

std::map<QQuickItem*, QQuickItem*>::iterator it = items.begin();
while (it != items.end()) {

    QQuickItem* item = it->first;
    QQuickItem * itemParent = it->second;  // no crash
    it++;
}
```

QML

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item
    {
        objectName: "quickitemObj1"
    }
    Item
    {
        objectName: "quickitemObj2"
    }
}
```

Comment: added null check. & also to demonstrate, I added a call to retrieve the width of the `QQuickItem` within the array loop which works fine. not sure what goes wrong when I add `QQuickItem*` to the map.

Comment: sorry about the confusion. corrected my question to demonstrate the exact code. pls take a look

Comment: @Programist Try my code now, what compiler do you use?

Comment: compiler is clang on osx. running the app as an osx app.

Comment: I got a minus vote because of a couple type issues in my question. @Macias is it possible for you to upvote now? as I have corrected the issue after the edit. this is only to get the negative vote reading off